# Does this laptop have an integrated or dedicated graphics processor?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics, amd-graphics-card

[properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQONi.jpg)

[DirectX Diagnostics general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPca4.png)

[DirectX Display dialogue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqEoj.png)

[DirectX Display dialogue 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4ZO.png)

[Screen Settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPnDB.jpg)

[Task Manager view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RenRB.png)

[System Information general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fthRA.png)

[detailed graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiHOx.png)

Please let me know if it would be helpful for me to manually translate any of the text included herein.

Either way, which CPU and (if applicable) independent graphics card does it have?

screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/tTwmO.png

stickers: i.stack.imgur.com/A4br3.png

The product description link says this computer boasts a separate GPU, but upon opening the device, I can find no actual evidence of such. In addition, the physical product itself features an "AMD Radeon Graphics" sticker on top of the one for its "Ryzen 7" processor.

For reference, its exact brand and model name is the AMD Ryzen 7 7730U. Regardless, would its rendering capabilities allow mid-level games to perform more smoothly than something with the Intel Evo i7-1360P?

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: It has Radeon graphics.  With leading VRAM configurations, excellent performance-per-dollar, and next generation features, AMD Radeon™ Graphics Cards deliver the best experience for PC gamers across 1080p, 1440p, and 4K. For full transparency, a competitive comparison with the appropriate Nvidia RTX graphics card is also provided.    ..... You could very simply have done your own research.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ZERO research done by author

Comment: That's entirely untrue. I outlined in the question above all the research I did, including visiting 100+ Google search results on how to determine if a laptop has a dedicated or integrated graphics processor, and 50+ pages of the same. Neither of your comments answered my question, either. Of course I'm aware it has Radeon graphics. Every computer has a GPU. My question was whether it was integrated into the system or not, as some are. Maybe try reading the question for more than 2 seconds next time.

Answer (score 1):

The AMD Ryzen 7 7730U is an [APU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_APU) (Accelerated Processing Unit). It is essentially an AMD processor combined with a GPU die. For all intents and purposes it is considered an "integrated" graphics solution.

The AMD Product page for the [AMD Ryzen 7 7730U](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-7-7730u) lists it as

> #### Graphics Capabilities
>
> **Graphics Model** AMD Radeon™ Graphics
> **Graphics Core Count** 8
> **Graphics Frequency** 2000 MHz

From your screenshots it appears to have allocated 512MB of system RAM as "dedicated" GPU memory.

You have a GPU integrated with your CPU and it uses your system RAM to work.

You do not have a discrete graphics card with it's own dedicated memory.

The APU graphics solutions were generally better than the Intel solutions of the same age and were generally considered far superior in terms of performance due to them being based on higher performance graphics cores, but savvy marketing trying to distance the "APU" as not really being the same as integrated graphics solutions does not change the fact that their place in a system is exactly the same as the "integrated" Intel solutions. They work the same, but just use better GPU cores.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! This was a very helpful answer. I had no idea APUs were a thing until just now. You say they "were" superior to Intel's graphics solutions from the same era, which confuses me a little bit because it makes it sound like they were a thing of the past or at the very least a discontinued line, yet the 7730U processor in question appears to have only been released earlier this year. What gives?

Comment: Given that this APU is functionally identical to an integrated memory solution rather than a dedicated GPU, why is it listed as the latter, especially when virtually all other comparable laptops being sold on the same platform are explicitly and distinctly categorized otherwise? Was this simply the result of human error and an honest mistake, or is the answer to that question just more complicated than can be described through a few short paragraphs? Could there even be something more nefarious at play here?

Comment: For reference, here's the link I mentioned earlier: https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/hp-envy-x360-15-oled-touchscreen-2-in-1-laptop-black-amd-ryzen-7-7730u-1tb-ssd-16gb-ram-win11/16998074

Comment: Finally, all things considered, would you recommend the Intel Evo i7-1360P over this one overall? It has 12 cores as opposed to 8, a slightly higher turbo-charged maximum speed, and runs on LPDDR5 rather than LPDDR4. I'm unable to glean much useful information from the various websites claiming to grade and compare different CPUs. Meanwhile the representative and store manager made it sound like the Ryzen 7 was far superior for gameplay performance due to its "dedicated" graphics status, but surely it can't make too much of a difference if it's effectively integrated into the processor anyway?

Comment: It is not a simple "honest mistake". It is either wilfully bending the truth almost to breaking point or plain wilful ignorance and just assuming that because it has the "Radeon" label that it must be a "real" graphics card. It is 100% marketing to try and avoid the stigma of "integrated graphics" by labelling it as something else when in actuality it is the same thing. I would absolutely never give marketing people the benefit of the doubt, if they tell you the sky is blue then you should go outside and check.

Comment: Integrated graphics solutions absolutely work better with more memory bandwidth so DDR5 could help a lot. Intel Xe graphics is one heck of a lot better than their previous graphic solutions and in some ways could have seriously caught up with low end Radeon. The 8 vs 12 core graphics is nearly impossible to.compare as they are substantially different architectures. Personally I would search YouTube for gaming benchmarks for both those processors.

Comment: @ET23 AMD 7730u https://youtube.com/watch?v=M8VUqukjjJ8 and then i7-1360p; https://youtube.com/watch?v=OKQXsbqsLK8 at a quick glance the benchmarks suggest that they are not very far apart.

Comment: so which one has the greater memory bandwidth, then? Sites like these seem to agree the i7-1360p is slightly superior, but I'm not sure how many of these benchmarks are related to graphics processing as opposed to other facets of their performance. https://versus.com/en/amd-ryzen-7-7730u-vs-intel-core-i7-1360p and https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/5215vs5198/AMD-Ryzen-7-7730U-vs-Intel-i7-1360P

Comment: @ET23 the Intel with DDR5 likely has slightly higher memory bandwidth, and that versus page is basically useless for getting any useful information. Without any benchmarking data at all versus.com just gives you a lot of numbers with no actual information. CPUbenchmark is better but is for the CPU, not the GPU, hence why i pointed you at youtube videos. The 3Dmark section at https://www.notebookcheck.net/i7-1360P-vs-R7-7730U-vs-i5-1340P_14731_14956_14735.247596.0.html suggests that the Intel 1360p performs better in 3D tasks, at least for whatever machine they tested.